How to customize the options of AvaloniaUI app on the finder in MacOS?
I don't understand how to modify the options like this picture below.

I tried to look up the official Avalonia Docs, but nothing about this can be found.
In MainView.axaml, I used the code to set the properties of main window.
<suki:SukiWindow x:Class="UotanToolbox.MainView"
                 xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:avalonia="clr-namespace:Material.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Material.Icons.Avalonia"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:demo="clr-namespace:UotanToolbox"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:suki="clr-namespace:SukiUI.Controls;assembly=SukiUI"
                 xmlns:assets="clr-namespace:UotanToolbox.Assets;assembly=UotanToolbox"
                 Title="Uotan Toolbox"
                 d:DesignHeight="450"
                 d:DesignWidth="1240"
                 x:DataType="demo:MainViewModel"
                 BackgroundAnimationEnabled="{Binding AnimationsEnabled}"
                 CanResize="{Binding !WindowLocked}"
                 Icon="Assets/OIG.N5o-removebg-preview.png"
                 IsMenuVisible="False"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">


Try to customize NativeMenu of main window or rather application. Here is bug report with code and screenshots.
